# Does Buffy eat garlic?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, food

We know that in the Buffyverse, garlic is effective against vampires:

> CLOSE: ON WINDOW
>
> Where a bunch of fresh garlic is now nailed.
>
> WIDEN
>
> To find that there is garlic nailed up at all the windows. Buffy sits up in bed, looking small and scared, holding a cross.

Source: the [script](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/scripts/110_scri.html) for *Wrecked*, season 6 episode 10.

This leads me to the question, does Buffy eat garlic? The smell must repulse vampires, adding an extra layer of protection.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0533391/trivia?item=tr2313607

Comment: “The smell must repulse vampires” — it might not.

Comment: Maybe she just knows Spike doesn't like it.  I mean, every other vamp (aside perhaps from Angel) would need an invitation, so the garlic could only be needed to protect against him while she wanted him away.  So, presumably there was a stretch of Season 6 where she didn't eat much garlic, and a stretch where she ate extra garlic. ;)

Comment: Well, the smell from the [Doublemeat Palace](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/Doublemeat_Palace) can drive 'em off...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In the original Buffy the Vampire Slayer (feature film) [script](http://www.buffyworld.com/buffy/transcripts/Original%20Movie%20Script.txt) we learn what books she was checking out from the Library.

> *Buffy charging some books: Lawson's Treatis on Demonology,
>   Psychological Interpretations of Vampirism, The Book of the Dead, and
>   **The Complete Garlic Cookbook.***

Within the TV series, there doesn't appear to be any instances of her eating raw garlic but she certainly doesn't shy away from eating [pizza](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=inurl%3Awww.buffyworld.com%20pizza&oq=inurl%3Awww.buffyworld.com%20pizza&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2715j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=inurl:www.buffyworld.com%20pizza&start=20), which you'd expect to contain some cooked garlic.